# High CPU load during flash playback

Tags: firefox, flash, cpu

I got a CPU load indicator applet and whenever I play a flash vid I see it going through the roof and staying high. I'm running 12.04 with the latest updates, restricted extras installed. Browser is Firefox.

Comment: Yup, that's Flash. What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

That's what Flash does.  It performs all video processing on the CPU instead of delegating the work to the GPU.  It is not efficient.